# Inkscape Punch Through Stroke

Tags: inkscape, transparency

I'd like to make the navy square transparent over the area where the white diamond is. Not the inner navy portion, just the white area. Is it possible to do this and end up with only one object?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Select the white object
2. Choose "Path" > "Stroke to path"
3. Select both objects and choose "Path" > "Difference". (The white object will need to be on top, which clearly it is in this case.)

Comment: Depending on what the asker wants and how the shadow is realised, the latter may also require some editing.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked perfectly. The shadow was included primarily for effect, to show the relationship between the two objects. Thanks very much to both of you!